# Covert into Bitmap from Sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I'm making an android game using andengine. I'm makin some sprites as object, where I can rotate sprite. But when I touch transparent part of image still it rotates the sprite.
To prevent this, I need to get Bitmap from Sprite. So can anyone provide method for that, by using that I can convert sprite to Bitmap.

I looked into this link.But in this it was using GLES1, but I'm working with GLES2.
 [bitmap for sprite follow this link for more](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/retriveing-bitmap-from-sprites-pixel-perfect-collision-t5103.html)

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/CanvasTextureCompositingExample.java

Comment: can you please explain how can I do this?  because I can't understand the code properly.

Comment: you asked this same question the other day

Comment: but I didn't get perfect answer, so I asked that question in different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not see this, there is a GLES2 version of Pixel-perfect collision. Its an android extension called "Andengine Collision Extension"

https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension

It should handle the case you are describing.

NOTE: You have to modify you copy of the Andengine source code to use the extension.